# How to pip install package without building its' C extensions?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, python-c-api

Is it possible to `pip install package` which provides optional C-extension, but specifically disable process of compiling those extensions?

Sample examples of such packages are:

- `_speedups` in [markupsafe](https://github.com/pallets/markupsafe/blob/master/setup.py)
- `_posixsubprocess32` in [subprocess32](https://github.com/google/python-subprocess32/blob/master/setup.py)

Answer (score 0):

It's not because it's `setup.py` that decides what and how to build. You have to download sources, unpack and edit `setup.py` to avoid building extensions.